# Where is the certificate input when I edit configure of iOS notification on PushWoosh

Tags: ios, pushwoosh

I remember that we have 3 fields when editing configure of iOS notification:

1. Certificate
2. p12 file
3. password of p12 file

But now I don't see "certificate" input. What happened?

Is it OK without certificate file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now you need only .p12 file. Certificate is not longer needed now. We'll update our guides soon, thanks!

Comment: Wow, really? Can I show the updating-post about this?

Comment: We update screenshot right now https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-configuration-guide/#Configure-push-notifications if it old please press CTRL +R (or MacOSX Key + R if you have MacOS X)

Comment: Now we back .cer field